# Do node js commit files are restoring on Heroku

Tags: node.js, json, heroku

I have a json file on my node js project.Im using it as database.
When I delete a post from my website.After a few hours it comes back.
Does the heroku have a system which restores the files automatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#ephemeral-filesystem

> Each dyno gets its own ephemeral filesystem, with a fresh copy of the
>   most recently deployed code. D**uring the dyno’s lifetime its running
>   processes can use the filesystem as a temporary scratchpad**, but no
>   files that are written are visible to processes in any other dyno and
>   **any files written will be discarded the moment the dyno is stopped or restarted**. For example, this occurs any time a dyno is replaced
>   due to application deployment and approximately once a day as part of
>   normal dyno management.

Everything that is versioned in git will be restored as it was. The filesystem on Heroku is temporary and will be reseted to its original state. If you want to have persistent storage you need to use a database server -> mongodb, postgresql, mysql server etc.